# SQL Procedure return value to one variable inside another procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

I have a procedure  , which return a single row of data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetABCD
AS 
declare  @_Wsd   varchar = 'England'
declare  @_App   varchar = '500'
declare  @_Ver   varchar = '1.0' 
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
select 
  @_Wsd as [WSDL_CODE]
  ,@_App as [APP_TYPE]
  ,@_Ver as [VERSION]     
END
```

The procedure  GetABCD is calling in another Procedure , and assign the three values to another variables in the calling procedure .

How can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the three values you want to return as `OUTPUT` values, and have the calling stored procedure use them from there on.

I.e. (pseudo code, i.e. untested)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetABCD
(
@_Wsd   varchar = 'England' OUTPUT
, @_App   varchar = '500' OUTPUT
, @_Ver   varchar = '1.0' OUTPUT
) 
select 
  @_Wsd as [WSDL_CODE]
  ,@_App as [APP_TYPE]
  ,@_Ver as [VERSION]     
RETURN
```

[More information here on MSDN.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure)

You can then consume the variables from another query or procedure.

As stated, this is untested, so you might have to slightly adjust the code. If it throws any error, please let me know, and I will update the answer accordingly.